# Vim color scheme with terminator

Tags: vim, terminator

I've been using terminator for a while, but I just noticed that it is not pulling in the correct color scheme from my .vimrc You can see from the image below that terminal is pulling in the correct color scheme, but terminator is not. I'm assuming it's because terminator has the 'color' option which overrides the one I have set up in .vimrc, but is there anyway to have it not do this? I'd prefer having the alternative version.

[image: Terminator vs Terminal]

This is my .vimrc

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plugin 'zeis/vim-kolor'
Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'vim-latex/vim-latex'
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
filetype plugin on

colorscheme kolor
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the `background` and `t_Co` options before you set the colorscheme.

```
set background=dark
set t_Co=256
```

Another option may be to adjust the terminator theme to be the same as the other terminal.